# How to get the comma separated values into rows like one below another oracle apex

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a apex item with values like Value1,Value2,Value3, so on  i need to show the values like below

Value 1

Value 2

Value 3

below is my select query, can anyone help here to show the comma seperated values as one below another
ex ::  a,b,c,d

i need to see the output as

a
b
c
d

```
SELECT  AD.EMAIL_ADDRESS recipient
FROM   HES_EXTERNAL_ACCOUNTS EA,
       HES_ADDRESSES         AD
WHERE  EA.ACCOUNT_CODE       = 'AUTO';
```

The above query will result the email address like a,b,c,d i need to show in apex item as
a
b
c
d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Chris Saxon's post describe many SQL scenarios, and a cool SQL macro, APEX provides a simple tool for splitting strings into rows:

```
select column_value from table(apex_string.split('a,b,c,d',','));

Result Sequence                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
----------------
a
b
c
d
```

That table() clause isn't required from a certain db version, perhaps 18c.

But your question isn't completely clear as to the output you need. On one hand it seems like you want to replace commas with spaces

```
replace('a,b,c,d', ',', ' ')
```

but then another moment you suggest one of top of the other

```
replace('a,b,c,d', ',', '<br>')
```

If displayed as a column in a report, this would need escaping turned off.

Answer (score 0):

If that select returns a single row, then this is a possible solution:

```
CREATE TABLE emails (email_list) AS (
select 'mickey.mouse@disney.com, homer.simpson@acme.com'
  from dual
);

Table EMAILS created.

  select TRIM(regexp_substr (
           email_list,
           '[^,]+',
           1,
           level
         )) email
  from   emails
  connect by level <= 
    length ( trim ( both ',' from email_list ) ) - 
    length ( replace ( email_list, ',' ) ) + 1;

EMAIL                                          
-----------------------------------------------
mickey.mouse@disney.com
homer.simpson@acme.com
```

But Chris has already done all the research and blogged about it [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/post/split-comma-separated-values-into-rows-in-oracle-database). That blog sums up most common cases and a solution in each of those cases.